# NuGet: Difference in behavior between Update-Package and nuget.exe update?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I'm using NuGet to create a 'web framework' package containing code, master pages, css, javascript, etc.

In an attempt to speed up the build / test process I'm running `nuget.exe update packages.config` but I've noticed that it behaves differently than the package manager console's `Update-Package` command.

- `nuget.exe update` seems to **leave the previous version of the package still installed**, resulting in multiple versions of the package installed.  This usually doesn't cause problems but the Package-Manager `Get-Package` command shows many versions installed and sometimes the project will fail to build.
- `Update-Package` actually **uninstalls the package then reinstalls it**, this is cleaner but slower

**My questions are:**
 1. Is there **documentation about the difference** / relationship between these commands
 2. Is the `nuget.exe update` behavior of **installing multiple versions a bug**?
 3. Is there a better **method for creating a package in one project and updating it in another project** in a fast & automated manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not much official guidelines or documentation except from piecing together forum and work item threads.

Current package manager console behavior was first included as a result from discussion in this [thread](https://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/256212), which later derived in a work item (sorry, apparently not enough rep to post more links).

However, [as others already noted](https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2802), behavior is not consistent with `nuget.exe`, where there's no such switch.

So, in answer to your questions:

1. VS Package Manager Console and `nuget.exe` do have different behaviors and seem to be updated independently (which is very unfortunate).
2. `nuget.exe` update behavior of installing multiple versions side-by-side has been a design feature from the start, as you can find from a comment on David Ebbo's blog about NuGet command line (again, I would have given you the link, but SO still doesn't trust me).
3. Unfortunately I haven't found anything about using package manager console cmdlets during build. What you could try is **manually deleting all folders with your packageId** on a build event and then **packaging and installing** using `nuget.exe`. Essentially replicate what `Update-Package` does manually, since as David Ebbo says, the way you uninstall a package through the command line interface is by, well, deleting the folder (again, can't post a reference, this is a bit annoying...)

Comment: Thanks for answering an overly broad question =) Once you have enough rep please include the missing links.  For now, we're just doing more testing within the source of our package to avoid headaches of automating the package installation during build.